Wired earphones not recognised
I have a pair of AKG wired earphones (USB-C - no adapter needed) and they will not connect to my phone (Samsung S22 Ultra)
Currently whenever I plug them in they seem to be recognised as a USB connector and thus will get this notification: 
I have tried a number of fixes from suggested by various forums and the issue still persists
Fixes I have attempted:

Restarting phone
Updating phone to latest version (as of time of post)
Force stopping 'Android system'
Ensured that 'disable USB audio routing' in developer options was turned off
Changed my default USB configuration settings in developer options (currently selected charging phone only)

I have also confirmed that this was not an issue with the earphones themselves as I have tested them on a friends phone as well as my laptop and they seem to work fine with other devices.
Any help would be appreciated

If you connect your phone via USB to a PC, does the connection works without problems (e.g. copying files from phone to PC)? Do the earphone work with other phones?

Yes, I have transferred files via USB before.
The earphones do work with other phones
